# How to run multiple functions on a list of arguments using threadpoolexecutor?

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool

I want to run multiple functions on a list of arguments using `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

When I use the following code, the functions are getting repeated with the same arguments and the code is running indefinitely.

```
thread_count = 0
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers) as executor:
    for i, itinerary_dict in enumerate(itinerary_list):
        results = []
        for _ in range(
            parser.getboolean('other', 'goibiboFlag')
            + parser.getboolean('other', 'mmtFlag')
            + parser.getboolean('other', 'emtFlag')
        ):
            if parser.getboolean('other', 'goibiboFlag'):
                if (
                    itinerary_dict['WEBSITE'] == 'ALL'
                    or itinerary_dict['WEBSITE'].lower().strip() == 'goibibo'
                ):
                    itinerary_dict['t_num'] = thread_count
                    results.append(
                        executor.submit(
                            goibibo.get_route_data, itinerary_dict, params
                        )
                    )
                    thread_count += 1

            if parser.getboolean('other', 'mmtFlag'):
                if (
                    itinerary_dict['WEBSITE'] == 'ALL'
                    or itinerary_dict['WEBSITE'].lower().strip() == 'mmt'
                ):
                    itinerary_dict['t_num'] = thread_count
                    results.append(
                        executor.submit(
                            mmt.get_route_data, itinerary_dict, params
                        )
                    )
                    thread_count += 1

            if parser.getboolean('other', 'emtFlag'):
                if (
                    itinerary_dict['WEBSITE'] == 'ALL'
                    or itinerary_dict['WEBSITE'].lower().strip() == 'emt'
                ):
                    itinerary_dict['t_num'] = thread_count
                    results.append(
                        executor.submit(
                            emt.get_route_data, itinerary_dict, params
                        )
                    )
                    thread_count += 1

        for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results):
            error_logger.info(f)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `for _ in range(...)`? You are passing booleans to a method meant to accept integers.

Comment: @flakes I am expecting the each boolean to convert to 1.

Comment: That probably explains your duplicate data. If each boolean is true, you will run each inner `executor.submit` statement three times each. Consider if you actually need that range check!

Comment: @flakes got it thanks. Now I feel stupid for asking this question.

Comment: We've all been there! No such thing as a dumb question. Coding is hard!